# Count characters in string, output chars sorted by occurance

Tags: go

I have a string and want to know how often each non-white-space character occurs.

The result should be sorted by count.

```
    data := `
    a
    bb
    ccc
    üüüü
    ddddd
    
    dd
    `
```

The result should be:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
ü 4
 6
d 7
```

How can I implement this with golang?

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    data := `
    a
    bb
    ccc
    üüüü
    ddddd
    
    dd
    `
    m := map[rune]int{}
    for _, char := range data {
        if unicode.IsSpace(char) {
            continue
        }
        m[char] += 1
    }
    chars := []rune{}
    for char := range m {
        chars = append(chars, char)
    }
    sort.Slice(chars, func(i, j int) bool {
        return m[chars[i]] < m[chars[j]]
    })
    for _, char := range chars {
        fmt.Printf("%c %d\n", char, m[char])
    }
}
```